# Extract field from document in aggregation framework as BSON bytes, not dict/object/Map

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, bson

Consider this document in a collection:

```
{
  data: {
    foo: "bar"
  },
  fld2: "baz"
}
```

I wish to run a pipeline to extract field `data` from the doc but as raw BSON bytes, something like this:

```
  db.foo.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {
        binary_byte_data: {$toBsonBytes: "$data"}
    }}
    ...
  ]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't possible, BSON is primarily used for internal storage purposes, and there is no operator to convert a field to bson bytes, as of now. Can I ask what is the use-case?

Comment: Running digests (e.g. SHA3) on sections of data.   Entirely possible from a client-side app; was experimenting driving the capability into the engine without any client side.